# Calculating volume using triple integrals for solids cut out

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

The prompt is to find the volume of the solid made by cutting out the ball $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1$ by a half cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

We know that in cylindrical coordinate system, $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$, $z = z$ and $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

Following this, we can find value of r and z from the 2 equations,
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$$
$$r^2 + z^2 = 1$$ equation 1
$$z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
$$z^2 = r^2$$ equation 2

From equations 1 and 2, we can tell $\frac{-1}{2} < r < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{-1}{2} < z < \frac{1}{2}$

Using these limits, we can construct the iterated integral as 
$$\int\int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{-1}{2}}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$ but I'm not sure how to find limits for $\theta$. Is this the correct way to solvethis problem?

Comment: Or you can use spherical coordinates. That would be much easier

Comment: Otherwise $\theta$ is just the projection of the solid on x y plane. in this case its a circle so limit would be 0 to $2\pi$

Comment: $r$ cannot be negative and $z$ is affected by the two surfaces. Is very useful a 3D plotting tool.

Answer (score 2):

Intersection sphere/cone:
$$r^2 + z^2 = 1, r^2 = z^2\implies r^2 = 1/2\implies r = \sqrt 2/2.$$ 
The correct limits are:
$$V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt 2/2}\int_r^{\sqrt{1 - r^2}}r\,dzdrd\theta.$$